# jQuery metisMenu not working with *ngIf

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-ng-if

We are using the metisMenu with Angular2, we have an *ngIf on one of the list items and that value is changed depending if a record is selected.  If it is then the li is shown to give additional options.

The problem is when it is visible it isn't working and clicking on that menu item reloads the page, if it is always visible then it works fine.  I assume the problem is that the ngIf removes it from the DOM completely and not just visibility so it isn't there when we initialise the metisMenu.  I have tried re-initialising the metisMenu but that doesn't seem to be working.

Is there a way to use the metisMenu and *ngIf on the li items?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove `*ngIf="isVisible"` and use `[style.visibility]="isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"` instead. This will prevent your elements from being removed from the DOM. There might be side effects though when the menu is styled via `last-of-type` or similar CSS selectors.

That aside, angular and jQuery really don't go together. You should try to get rid of jQuery as quickly as possible. It has nothing to offer angular doesn't.

Comment: I think you are right, I am just going to strip the jquery out and use Angular, much simpler.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your reinitialization code in a `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(() => { jQuery('#elem').metisMenu(); }, 0);
```

What you could also do is make a directive that takes metisMenu options as an `@Input`, then apply this directive on your items that have *ngIf. Show us the code for further advice.

For example:

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appMetisMenu]'
})
export class MetisMenuDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() options: {} = {};

    constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).metisMenu(this.options);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try this as an experiment rather than a long-term solution and it doesn't seem to work.  Unless the *ngIf evaluates to true from the beginning the menu doesn't appear to work for the newly visible elements.  It still works fine for the elements which were already visible.